# How to use virtualization on guest VM (windows 8.1) in virtualbox which is on a virtualization enabled CPU running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-7-x64, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a 16GB laptop running on Intel core i7 processor. I have Windows 7 Enterprises installed on this machine. Now, I need to do some work around the Windows 8.1 Pro and need to run the emulator on Windows 8.1 Pro.

So, I have installed the virtualbox on my machine and installed the Windows 8.1 Pro on a VM in virtualbox.

I have enabled the Virtualization on my machine using the BIOS settings, but it is not reflected in the Windows 8.1 VM. And I have to enable the Hyper-V Platform from windows features for running the emulator, but it is not possible until virtualization is reflected in Windows 8.1 VM as well.

So, please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called *nested virtualization* (i.e. the ability to run a virtual machine into another). Unfortunately, it seems that VirtualBox [does not support nested virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032). You can try other virtualization solutions that support this feature (like VMware Player).